# Imploding array within a foreach loop (PHP) to build a SQL query: invalid argument error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, implode

I'm trying to build a SQL query by looping in PHP using 2 arrays (one of which is array of arrays):

```
    //build array of arrays using predefined arrays
$regions = array_filter(array($EAPRO, $WCARO, $ROSA, $TACRO, $MENA, $ESARO));

//just a normal array
$regionnames = array('EAPRO', 'WCARO', 'ROSA', 'TACRO', 'MENA', 'ESARO');

$sql = "";

foreach(array_combine($regions, $regionnames) as $region => $regionname)
{
$sql .="UPDATE `database`.`table` SET `region`='$regionname' 
WHERE `countryname` IN (" . implode(",",$region) . ");";
}
echo $sql;
```

However, debugging this in ideone gives me:

```
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed on line:
UPDATE `database`.`table` SET `region`='ESARO' WHERE `countryname` IN ();
```

Which tells me that the array on each loop is not being imploded correctly. Is there something wrong with the way I've defined my array of arrays?

Thanks

Comment: is $region defined ? I don't think so, so try implode(",",$regions)

Comment: Hmm, `$region` should be defined by the loop: `foreach(array_combine($regions, $regionnames) as $region => $regionname)` so on any given loop $region should be set to one of the arrays defined in `$regions` no?

Comment: my bad it slipped from my sight ...

Comment: No probs :) thanks for looking.

Comment: Hmmm didn't you "flip" in array_combine($regions, $regionnames) the variables ? From the docs it's said http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php: array array_combine ( array $keys , array $values ). Try array_combine($regionnames, $regions)

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV I don't quite understand what you mean, could you explain the alternative in an answer so I can see? If it works out this also means I can credit you with solving! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18381/discussion-between-hamza-dzcyberdev-and-gideon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php): `array_combine ( array $keys , array $values )`

So the problem is that the variables are in the wrong places `array_combine($regions, $regionnames)` (a key can never be an array).

So this should fix the problem:

```
    //build array of arrays using predefined arrays
$regions = array_filter(array($EAPRO, $WCARO, $ROSA, $TACRO, $MENA, $ESARO));

//just a normal array
$regionnames = array('EAPRO', 'WCARO', 'ROSA', 'TACRO', 'MENA', 'ESARO');

$sql = "";

foreach(array_combine($regionnames, $regions) as $region => $regionname)
{
$sql .="UPDATE `database`.`table` SET `region`='$regionname' 
WHERE `countryname` IN (" . implode(",",$region) . ");";
}
echo $sql;
```